# How to get all the data before the current date and data for the next 3 days from current date.DATEDIFF(now(),d.tentative_date_of_return) <= now() + 3

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
d.name AS "ID:Link/Demo Request:120",    
d.requester_name AS "Requester Name:Data:190",    
d.customer_name AS "Customer Name:Data:250",    
d.date_of_request AS "Date Of Request:Date:120",    
d.tentative_date_of_return AS "Tentative Date Of Return:Date:170",    
d.material_sent_from_location AS "Material Sent From Location:Data:190",    
d.delivery_note AS "Delivery Note:Data:100",    
d.material_status AS "Material Status:Data:120",    
d.product_supplied_condition AS "Product Supplied Condition:Data:150",    
d.courier_service AS "Courier Service:Data:120",    
d.shipped_date_from_rahi AS "Shipped Date From Rahi:Date:120",    
d.tracking_no AS "Tracking No:Data:120",    
DATEDIFF(now(),d.tentative_date_of_return) AS "No Of Days:Data:100"

FROM    
`tabDemo Request` as d

WHERE    
d.material_status not like "Recieved From Customer"    
AND    
DATEDIFF(now(),d.tentative_date_of_return) <= now() + 3

ORDER BY d.tentative_date_of_return ASC
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `tentative_date_of_return`?

Comment: `AND    
DATEDIFF(now(),d.tentative_date_of_return) <= now() + 3` DATEDIFF gives you a small INTEGER as a difference. You try to compare it with expression. In this expression the datetime of NOW is converted into DECIMAL with the value over 2*10^14 for addition (see [Conversion Between Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html)). So the result will be always TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
AND d.tentative_date_of_return <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: Thanks @rick james